# Can we insert data into existing table using Hcatalog?

Tags: hcatalog

I am learning Pig and Hive. I came across one concept of HCatalog. I try to load table using HCatalog in pig and i succeeded in that. Now, i want to use HCatstorer. if there is table already exist in hive then can insert new data in existing table using HCatalog?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can load data to existing table. It creates new files under the existing directory. By default using HCatalog APIs will not overwrite the existing data.

Comment: okk....but in existing partition we cannot insert data. right? In table we can but in partition we can not?

Comment: We can insert data to existing partition... Hcatalog APIs will take partition as well...For example while writing output we can specify the partition to write... OutputJobInfo create(String databaseName, String tableName, Map<String,String> partitionValues)